# Disable customer attribute in magento admin form

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, grid, forms

I created custom customer attribute  `is_institution` with boolean value

My `installData.php` is

```
<?php
namespace xxx\xxxx\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    private $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,\Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository)
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // add customer_attribute to customer
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_institution');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_institution', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Is Institution',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'system' => false,
            'position' => 100
                ]
        );

        // allow customer_attribute attribute to be saved in the specific areas
    $attribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get('customer', 'is_institution');
    $setup->getConnection()
    ->insertOnDuplicate(
        $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
        [
            ['form_code' => 'adminhtml_customer', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_create', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_edit', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

It is displayed in admin customer form

[image]

But I want to disable it from admin form, so the admin cannot modify this attribute

I also tried **'readonly' => true,** but it is not working

Comment: Did you use Ui component?

Comment: no , i created customer attribute . is need to ui component?

Comment: Pls add  'visible' => false  in your script & run again

Comment: i try attribute created but i cant see admin view. I want not editable

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Comment: No, You got any solution?

Comment: If you do find a solution then I would like to know as well

Answer (score 18):

You need to create `Namespace/Module/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` and add the following code

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="is_institution" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I hope this solution will solve your problem.
Thanks

Comment: yes  its working

Comment: working for me as well. any idea if there is a setting to keep the toggle on/off aspect? for me the toggle turned into an input field with the value 1 or 0. I have a boolean field.

Comment: Can you please add your code so I can check and give the proper answer?
Thanks

Comment: @Shankar I'm using the code you've provided in the answer. The only difference is the field name which shouldn't matter.

Comment: Did you created custom customer attribute?

Comment: @Shankar, I am also getting same issue. My custom customer attribute type is boolean. If I use your code to make it read only then it is converted into text box.. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Radu I have resolved this issue. You need to set formElement="checkbox" instead of formElement="input" in above code. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Or in more recent versions of Magento...

And using [@Shankar example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/244251/4659)

> You need to create Namespace/Module/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml and add the following code

```
<fieldset name="customer">
    <field name="is_institution">
        <settings>
            <disabled>1</disabled>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this line from your code

```
 ['form_code' => 'adminhtml_customer', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
```

your code should be like this

```
<?php
namespace xxx\xxxx\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    private $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,\Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository)
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // add customer_attribute to customer
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_institution');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'is_institution', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Is Institution',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'system' => false,
            'position' => 100
                ]
        );

        // allow customer_attribute attribute to be saved in the specific areas
    $attribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get('customer', 'is_institution');
    $setup->getConnection()
    ->insertOnDuplicate(
        $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
        [
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_create', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_edit', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: It hidden from customer form . but i want display values, but Admin user con't change that value, because it update form some other DB .